# property injection without annotation not working spring + jersey

Tags: java, spring, rest, dependency-injection, jersey

i am integrating spring-jersey. i am trying to inject property without annotation(@InjectParam). this code is not working.I strictly need it to inject without using annotation.

**here is my  Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Jersey Example</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>\WEB-INF\dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</param-name>
             <param-value>org.jersey.examples</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jersey.examples" />

    <bean id="springBean" class="org.jersey.examples.SpringBeanExample" />

    <bean id="jerseySimple" class="org.jersey.examples.JerseySimpleExample">
        <property name="springBean" ref="springBean" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**SpringBeanExample.java**

```
package org.jersey.examples;

public class SpringBeanExample{

    public String getValue(){
        return "Spring and Jersey Integration";
    }
}
```

**JerseySimpleExample.java**

```
package org.jersey.examples;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/hello")
public class JerseySimpleExample {

    private SpringBeanExample springBean;

    @GET
    @Path("/javabeat")
    public Response getMessage() {
        String result = springBean.getValue();
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

    public void setSpringBean(SpringBeanExample springBean) {
        this.springBean = springBean;
    }
}
```

When I hit the URL webservice doesnot get hit.
This code works properly when i use @InjectParam and remove jerseySample bean from dispatcher-servlet.xml.
please help.